# How do I Enable devTokens on getstream.io?

Tags: getstream-io

on this page it says "To enable development tokens, you need to change your application configuration."

https://getstream.io/chat/docs/tokens_and_authentication/?language=js

to allow use of

```
await client.setUser(
    {
        id: 'john',
        name: 'John Doe',
        image: 'https://getstream.io/random_svg/?name=John',
    },
   client.devToken('john'),
);
```

I have changed the app type to 'development' in the getstream dashboard but I still get the following error:

Error: {"code":5,"StatusCode":401,"message":"WS failed with code 5 and reason - development tokens are not allowed for this application","isWSFailure":false}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable auth checks in the dashboard.

First one in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: found in "Chat messaging" -> "Overview", scroll down a bit